# Vuejs check a row to see if it's not null

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm retrieving an object from my database and somme fields are nullable. I don't know how to check a particular  to know the value.

```
<tr v-for="soin in soins" :key="soin.id">
  <td>{{soin.date}}</td>
  <td>{{soin.typesoin.name}}</td>
  <td>{{soin.categoriesoin.name}}</td>
  <td>{{soin.price}}</td>
  <td>{{soin.priceWithReduction}}</td>

  <!-- Nullable -->
  <td>{{soin.rabaisraison.name}}</td> 
  <!-- If null display nothing, if not, display value. -->
```

Same when I'm passing data to editing

```
<!--Buttons-->
                    <td>
                        <b-button @click="editingModalSoin(

                            soin.date, soin.price, soin.priceWithReduction, soin.referedBy, //Values

                            soin.moyendepaiement.id, soin.rabaisraison.id, 

                            soin.boncadeau.id, soin.bonreduction.id,//FK can be equal to null how do I do that

                            soin.categoriesoin.id, soin.typesoin.id,//FK
                            soin.id//rowid


                        ); setCRUDState('edit')"> <font-awesome-icon icon="edit" /></b-button>

                        <b-button @click="deleteSoin(soin.id)"> <font-awesome-icon icon="trash" /></b-button>
                    </td>
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: You don't need to worry about it in this case, `null` is already nothing so nothing will display and when you call `editingModalSoin` it'll just pass a `null` value for that parameter.  Also I would just pass the object to `editingModalSoin` instead of individual parameters to clean your markup up so just `@click="eidtingModalSoin(soin)"`.

Comment: I get this though : Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null"

Comment: Oh sorry I just saw it was a nested property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `v-if`:

```
<td>
  <template v-if="soin.rabaisraison">
  {{soin.rabaisraison.name}}
  </template>
</td>
```

If `name` is null it'll print nothing so you only need to check it's parent in this case.

Comment: It works perfectly for the displaying, do you have an idea for passing the parameters if they are null? (soin.rabaisraison.id , soin.boncadeau.id, soin.bonreduction.id)

Comment: As noted in my above comment, I would pass the entire object as a parameter to  `editingModalSoin` instead of individual parameters.  This way you can do null checks in your function and it'll clean up your markup.